# Convert UK Bachelor Degree Grades to German Grade Scale

Tags: graduate-school, grades, germany

I have a Bachelor of Business Administration in Information Systems (3rd Class Honors) form a UK University. My Transcript states as follows.

```
Course Name    Marks    Cats
BUS            40       12
```

How do I convert these to the German Grading System?

[German Grading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_Germany)

[Understanding German Grades](http://www.ssag.de/studying-in-germany/why-germany/grades/)

I have gone through the above but can't figure out how to calculate the UK (40 Marks and 12 Cats) to the German Grades (scale of 1 to 5) and also how to figure out the ECTS (European Credit Transfer and Accumulation System).

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: It's not a duplicate. I have go through that answer. My Question is more specific and narrower in scope.

Comment: The answers to the duplicate question say don't do it. On the surface your question might be different, but the answer is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no universal system available for converting grades between national systems. For instance, in Germany, each university and even each faculty within a university may have its own system for "translating" grades from one system to another, and grades obtained between courses are not necessarily directly translatable. For instance, 70% of the points on an exam in one subject might constitute a 1,3 in one subject but (for instance) a 2,3 in another subject.

The only reliable rules are:

- A 4,0 (4.0) is the minimum passing grade in any subject in a German university.
- In classes where written exams are administered, the scale above 4,0 should be as uniform as possible. (In other words, the difference between the minimum points for a 1,0 or a 1,3 should be the same as between a 2,0 and a 2,3.)

But, as you can see, this still allows for a lot of latitude between different subjects.

Comment: how about the "modified Bavarian formula". Best possible grade in your grading system (100) - The final grade achieved in your bachelor's programme (40) / Best possible grade in your grading system (100) - Minimum passing grade in your grading system (40) X 3 +1 -- http://www.tum.de/en/studies/before-your-studies/application-and-acceptance/grade-conversion-formula-for-grades-earned-outside-germany/

Comment: The reason I state this is because of the admission requirements. I have to provide a course description of my Bachelor which should have the German Grades Calculated.

Comment: It's OK, but it's not all that precise—and it violates the second point listed above.